# Script to remove all files from a text file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file-io

I am creating a script that will copy all files mentioned in a text file to some destination.

This is my script:

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = 'cp ' + line + ' /root/dest1'
        print a
        os.system(a)
```

This is print below commands:

```
( Incorrect )

cp 91.txt
 /root/dest1
cp 92.txt
 /root/dest1
cp 93.txt
 /root/dest1
...
```

While it should print like this:

```
(correct)

cp 91.txt /root/dest1
cp 92.txt /root/dest1
cp 93.txt /root/dest1
...
```

This is my file

```
(names.txt)

91.txt
92.txt
93.txt
94.txt
95.txt
96.txt
97.txt
98.txt
99.txt
9.txt
```

Can anyone help me with the issue. By the way, I am printing commands just to know what is wrong.

Comment: you want to remove the line break on the variable line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating a file yields lines. Each line contains newline.

Strip newlines using [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) or [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = 'cp ' + line.rstrip() + ' /root/dest1'
        #  a = 'cp {} /root/dest1'.format(line.rstrip())
        print a
        os.system(a)
```

If you use [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy), you don't need to use `os.system`:

```
import shutil

with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        shutil.copy(line.rstrip(), '/root/dest1')
```